# react fragment throwing unexpected token div error

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an `Iterator` component inside my app which iterates over a given set of items and prints them to the page. Usually, the component works just fine. However, I've encountered a weird issue with **React**, where - despite the child components being wrapped in a `Fragment` component, **React** will still throw `unexpected token div`.

```
const Iterator = ({ items, children, ...props }) => (
    <div {...props}>
        { items.map((data, key) => (
            <Fragment key={key}>
                { children(data, key) }
            </Fragment>
        ))}
    </div>
);

// This "parent" element is the one that throws the error. 
<div className={styles.parent}>
    <Iterator items={items} className={styles.child}>{itemValue => (
        <Fragment>
            { itemValue?.type === "a" && (
                <div>A</div>
            )}
            { itemValue?.type === "b" && (
                <div>B</div>
            )}
        </Fragment>
    )}</Iterator>
</div>
```

Only when I remove one of the `itemValue?.type === ...` blocks does the code render as expected.

I may be missing something, but I can't put my finger on it. What's wrong here?

Comment: codesandbox  link?

Comment: I cannot reproduce any such problem ~ https://codesandbox.io/s/sad-forest-qzynkn?file=/src/App.js. FYI you cannot use `// ...` comments in JSX, it must be `{/* ... */}`

Comment: @Phil `// ...` was used just to illustrate that there is additional code there; it was not actually in my code. I've now updated to reflect that.